Google's "review account activity" has only one entry for a password change. Is it possible other entries were deleted?
I had a phone that got stolen.. it last synced at about 6am today..
I changed the password on my google account.
If I go to https://myaccount.google.com/find-your-phone
It says

and if I click "review activity"
it says

The password change on my google account was me.
Google's "review account activity" has only one entry for a password change. Is it possible other entries were deleted?

Add screen messages a text. Also clarify the problem to be solved.

I don't understand what you  mean. You say "Add screen messages a text" What does that mean?  Also you're asking "clarify the problem to be solved". I don't understand what you want,. I have asked a question and i'm interested in if people have teh answer. The question is "Google's "review account activity" has only one entry for a password change. Is it possible other entries were deleted?"

What part of that question isn't clear? I even included pictures. If you want it framed as problem/solution instead of question/solution (and the site seems to me to be about questions and solutions). the problem, i'm speaking of is the review activity seems to be clear, and i'm wondering if it is possible that it was wiped. Or maybe if it gets wiped when you change password. Perhaps somebody knows.
